# Ionic 3 - a tag href internal link

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

So I'm new to Ionic and Angular and I had a question regarding internal links within the Ionic framework. So as a learning base I made the pre-made project ionic sidemenu and I'm trying to get an A tag on the home page to be linked (href) to open the list page. However, I cannot figure it out because I keep getting errors.

Something like:

```
<a button href="../list/list.html"></a>
```

But the href isn't working because I think you have to call /list/list as a package with typescript??

Does anyone know the solution?

Comment: I looked at https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation and https://ionicframework.com/docs//intro/tutorial/navigation/ but still can't figure it out. This is my code for what I'm making. It says "goToOtherPage() is not a function". https://jsfiddle.net/ng16rL44/1/

Answer (score 1):

You're doing it wrong. Ionic has its own navigation system.So you need to use it to navigate one page to another or like so.

```
this.nav.push(listpage);
```

Please see the official doc for more info about [**navigation**](https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation) and [**NavController**](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! I know I'm answering my own question but just in case anyone else got stuck.

https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation

Make sure that the goToOtherPage() function is NOT in the constructor but only the export class in the typescript file.